# Extend AND implement in the same class

Tags: java, extends, implements

How can I implement an interface AND extend a class to the same class?

This doesn't seem to work (the interface is not implemented at all):

```
public class StrongChecker extends BasicChecker implements Checker {
```

This doesn't work either (the interface is not implemented at all):

```
public class StrongChecker extends BasicChecker {
```

And this gives me an error:

```
public class StrongChecker implements Checker extends BasicChecker {
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think I made a mistake, correct me if Im wrong but the first option works, I figured it didnt work because I hadnt put any methods in StrongChecker and got no errors, assumed it was because the interface wasnt implemented but obviously StrongChecker got the methods it needed from BasicChecker

Comment: Some times asking the question is what leads you to finding the answer.

Comment: The poster seems to have realised that the problem was not a problem.

Comment: Does BasicChecker implement Checker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with:

```
public class StrongChecker extends BasicChecker implements Checker {
```

Of course, your `StrongChecker` class has to implement all the methods of `Checker` (or inherit implementations from `BasicChecker`), or the code won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this syntax:

```
public class StrongChecker extends BasicChecker implements Checker {
```

This is perfectly fine just make sure you actually implement all the methods that need implementation in your interface or you will get an error.

Comment: This thinking is what lead to my problem lol, I implemented all the methods from the interface in BasicChecker and nothing in StrongChecker, then you get no errors in StrongChecker because it extends BasicChecker that does have all the methods in it already haha

Comment: If all the methods that need implementation are implemented in my BasicChecker then StrongChecker will not give you errors because it gets the methods that need implementation from BasicChecker because StrongChecker extends BasicChecker